# VBA - Date variable inside hashtags?

Tags: vba, date, debugging

I was debugging my application and I had a peek on the date filter of the pivottable. It showed the following:

[image]

Apparently the value of the Value1 and Value2 variables are enclosed within hashtags. What does it mean? If I create a Date variable with the `DateSerial()` function, it does not put the returned value in hashtags.

Comment: It's just how dates are represented as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just how date objects are defined / displayed as strings.

[Date VB Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) - see Format Requirements for the reason why this exists. (Locale differences)

If you do

```
Dim EndFeb As Date = DateSerial(-10, 3, 0)
```

you should get hashtags, per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c(v=vs.90).aspx).